# Does SQL Agent Job close when a user closes the dialogue box which shows the status of running job?

Tags: sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I ran a job in SQL Server agent. However mistakenly I closed the dialogue box which shows up when you select on "Star the Job". Does that mean that job has stopped/cancelled?

P.S : I dont have access to check the currently running job on server visa SQL Server query.

Answer (score 0):

using job activity monitor. or EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @Job_name

Answer (score 0):

No, the job keeps on running. If the job has multiple steps and the first steps has completed, you can check its progress by right-clicking on the job and selecting `View History`.